# Get all running activities from Google Fit via REST API

Tags: rest, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

Is there a way to get all activities from the Google fitness store via the [REST API](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/)?

My current assumption is that other apps store their activities in sessions and I can retrieve them using [Users.sessions.list](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/sessions/list). However, the information there, does not really include all the information that was stored or I would like to see: when I manually add a short run via the Fit Android app, I expect this information to be somehow accessible via the sessions API. This should at least include the information I have provided, such as distance or time.

Looking at the same information via the app or the [web interface](https://fit.google.com), I can see all the details I have previously entered plus the approximate number of steps and calories.

[image]

How do I get this information via the API?

I am currently mainly interested in activities of [type](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/activity-types) running or jogging (8, 56-58) and would like to read the distance in addition to the time information already provided in the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, if this is the right way, but I get all the information I need, if I follow these steps

1. Find the correct session via [Users.sessions.list](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/sessions/list)
2. Query all data via [Users.datasets.aggregate](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataset/aggregate):

   - Set `startTimeMillis` and `endTimeMillis` to the values from the session in question
   - Set `bucketBySession` to group results by sessions.
   - I explicitly query all data sources: For every data source id I add a `{ "dataSourceId": <id>`}`to the`aggregateBy` array. Not sure, if this is necessary

The resulting bucket has all information related to the session. For my use case I need to clean up overloaded data: some data sources return the distance as steps (derived) while I need the physical length in meters.

This seems to work for my Fit data with the additional cleaning, but I will need to check, if this works for other user's data too.

Comment: Thanks, could you kindly elaborate which dataSourceId you are using?